Understanding the Transition from the Traditional Derivative Definition to Spivak's Reformulation OR Preparation for differentiation R(n)
I’m reading Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, and I’m having trouble understanding a reformulation of the derivative definition he introduces early in Chapter 2 (page 15).
The traditional definition of the derivative for a function $( f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} )$ is:
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}.
$$
Spivak reformulates this as:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - \lambda(h)}{h} = 0,
$$
where $\lambda(h) = f'(a) h$.
It seems that we’re somehow moving ( f'(a) ), which is outside the limit in the traditional definition, inside the limit in Spivak’s version. I'm struggling to understand why these two forms are equivalent and what exactly this reformulation accomplishes.
Specifically:

How does Spivak's definition ensure we still recover ( f'(a) ) as the slope of the tangent line?
Why is introducing $\lambda(h)$ (a linear approximation term) necessary, and how does this help when transitioning to functions $ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $?
Is there a way to intuitively see why $ \lambda(h)/h \to f'(a) $ (assuming it's okay to bring f'(a) inside the limit in the first place)?
(Bonus) Looking ahead (page 16), I don't see why he couldn't have just kept the traditional definition of the derivative and used the "norm" (| |) signs with that.  That, actually seems the key to defining the derivative with dimensions > 1

Any insights or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!
Extras:

No, I'm not taking a class. This is to keep my 60 yr. old brain active.  I'm fairly conversant with 1st year calculus (from minoring in math eons ago and helping my kids with 1st year calc homework).
Yes, I did ask ChatGPT :).  I didn't understand the answer.  It was surprisingly helpful with the math formatting for this question though!
I was told that Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" is one of the truly great math books.  If you disagree or think other books would be more appropriate (based on my question) feel free to say so. I checked it out from the library. It must be fairly famous if my local public library has it :)


Take a look at Advanced Calculus by Folland, chapter 2

This question has a clear focus. I don’t find its closure convincing.

Thank you very much @SineoftheTime for the Folland link. Very good and I believe will answer my questions. For others... It's free on Folland's website. Do a Google search.   Too bad the question was closed. I still think it's an interesting question. It forces one to look at the derivative in a different way. Cheers

@Dave  Glad  to be helpful. The question was closed because it has 4 different questions. Edit it limiting it to one and it'll probably be reopened

Suppose $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$. We want to show that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) - L = 0$. This is equivalent to showing that, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that $|x - a|< \delta$ implies $|(f(x) - L) - 0|< \epsilon$.
Well, given our assumption, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-a|< \delta$ imples $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. And so we have $|(f(x) - L) - 0| < \epsilon$.
You can now apply this to Spivak's formulation with $L = f'(a)$.

Sorry, not following your reasoning at all. Are you arguing that (after making L = f'(a) that f(x) - L goes to 0?  That doesn't make sense.  I'm missing something in your argument. Thanks for the answer though.
